# Horizontal navigation in sidenav Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Can you please tell me if it is possible to implement navigation as in the following example? Only with the Angular Material. Thank you.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ksfo7fnSB0c4DH6egE3S?p=preview&preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" layout="row">
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="true">
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content  ng-controller="RightCtrl" class="main-ctr md-padding">
<div ng-show="mainMenu" class="mainmenu">        <md-list>
                <md-list-item>
                    <md-icon aria-label="home" class="material-icons"
                             style="">home
                    </md-icon>
                    <p class="md-body-2 side-nav-item">Home</p>
                </md-list-item>
                <md-list-item ng-click="nav('back')">
                    <md-icon aria-label="settings" class="material-icons">settings
                    </md-icon>
                    <p class="md-body-2 side-nav-item">Settings</p>
                      <md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button" ng-click="nav('back')">
                        <md-icon aria-label="chevron_right" class="material-icons">chevron_right</md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </div>  
<div ng-show="submenu" ng-class="{donotshow:donotshow, submenu: true}" > 

          <md-list>
                  <md-list-item  ng-click="nav('main')">
                      <md-icon aria-label="chevron_left" class="material-icons"
                                 ng-click="nav('main')">chevron_left
                      </md-icon>
                      <p class="md-body-2 side-nav-item">Back</p>
                  </md-list-item>
                  
                  <md-list-item>
                      <md-icon aria-label="people" class="material-icons"
                               style="">people
                      </md-icon>
                      <p class="md-body-2 side-nav-item">My Profile</p>
                  </md-list-item>
                  <md-list-item>
                    <md-icon aria-label="people" class="material-icons"
                               style="">people
                      </md-icon>
                      <p class="md-body-2 side-nav-item">account</p>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
        </div> 
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Perhaps there is a decent solution out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to implement it by using stepper API.
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview